# PySpark Row with Label and Features vs LabeledPoint

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I saw a PySpark Spark SQL example where this syntax is being used to do something similar to what creating a LabeledPoint in Spark Mllib does:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors

rdd2 = rdd1.map(lambda x: Row(label=float(x[-1]), features=Vectors.dense(x[:-1]))

rdd2.take(2)

[Row(features=DenseVector([540.0, 0.0, 0.0, 162.0, 2.5, 1040.0, 676.0, 28.0]), label=79.99),
 Row(features=DenseVector([540.0, 0.0, 0.0, 162.0, 2.5, 1055.0, 676.0, 28.0]), label=61.89)]
```

The alternative method with Spark Mllib is:

```
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint

rdd3 = rdd1.map(lambda x: LebeledPoint(label=float(x[-1]), features=Vectors.dense(x[:-1])))

rdd3.take(2)

[LabeledPoint(79.99, [540.0,0.0,0.0,162.0,2.5,1040.0,676.0,28.0]),
 LabeledPoint(61.89, [540.0,0.0,0.0,162.0,2.5,1055.0,676.0,28.0])]
```

I was wondering if there is any difference to these two examples and whether if one is better than the other?